Excel, VBA, disable "Invalid formula" error dialog
I've got a simple class thats executes SQL query, then fill array with query results, next convert it into Range, a finally there is a list object created:
Dim data() As Variant
...
ReDim data(0 To rowCount, 1 To colCount)
... populating data
Set rng = Range("A1:" & ColumnLetter(colCount) & CStr(rowCount + 1))
rng = data << Exception is raised here
Dim Tbl As ListObject
Set Tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes)

What I want to achieve is to enable, that query returns excel formula, for example, i can add to my select query:
SELECT
...
'=2*A1' AS COL1

And it works (=2*A1 is stupid/useless example, but i want to explain what i mean).
Now, i want to use structured references formulas, for example:
SELECT
...
T.SALE AS SALE,
'=[@Sale]/AGGREGATE(9;5;[Sale])' AS SALE_PART,"
...

but the problem is that [Sale] i a reference to table column - which doesn't exist yet, at a data population moment - so VBA throws exceptions - "Out of memory". I dont know why is about out of memory, but im sure its about cell with that formula (other cells before that one, are populated correctly).
So - the question is - can I temporary disable somehow formula validation (prevent error dialog) ? I could then reenable it, after creating a listobject, and then those problematic formulas will gone ([Sale] become a valid reference)
I think, the problem is connected with structured references. When I enter invalid formula like:
=xyz
there is no error dialog, but this formula is incorrect (#NAME?), but when i enter:
=[xyz]
there is a dialog box :(

You could disable events with Application.EnableEvents = False, but instead of fudging and breaking things only to fix them later, why not do it right from the start? You seem to be complicating things unnecessarily. If you know you will be using a table later on, create it first without any data so you can reference it in your formulas properly.

The problem is that I wasn't expect to use references to table columns. But now I see that it makes generating reports much easier. I asked the question to find the simplest solution without having to modify my toolset. I already have EnableEvents, ScreenUpdating set to False. I also set Calculation = xlCalculationManual but it didn't help.

For now, I ve found a workaround for the problem - when inserting texts into cells, I precede them with the ' sign, and then, after creating the table, I do:
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Tbl.DataBodyRange
    If InStr(1, cell.Value, "=") = 1 Then
        cell.Formula = cell.Value
    EndIf
Next

It works for now, but it's not a perfect solution.
